# SSRS Multifield Parameter - All Selected Parameter Fields or None

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I am creating a report for a blood bank to search for red blood cells that are antigen negative (multi parameter), as well as the blood type.

I am unable to get my multifield parameter to show all or nothing when multiple values are selected. In my query I am using the IN statement, which explains why if I put c-,E- in the parameter field it will show EITHER c- OR E-.

Is there a different statement or way to get a multifield parameter to include ALL selected parameter fields that have been selected, but not include any of them if one parameter field is not present?

I am also getting case insensitive results, if I select little c it will show me C- and c- which are different antigens that need to be searched for separately.

Yellow - only one parameter value is met
Purple - Case insensitivity, C- should not be present
Red - Case insensitivity, Little e should not be present

[Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goPMq.png)

Here is the query I am working with

```
SELECT DISTINCT
PH.blood_type
, PH.unit_number
, S.status_code
, a.antigen_code
, PH.expires
, S.location_code
, PH.product_code

FROM
product_latest_status S
INNER JOIN product_header PH ON S.product_id = PH.product_id
INNER JOIN lab_unit AS lu ON lu.unit_number = PH.unit_number

CROSS APPLY tvf_AntigensForDonor(lu.donor_id) a

WHERE        
(PH.blood_type = @BloodType) 
AND (PH.expires >= GETDATE()) 
AND (PH.product_code = 'E0209') 
AND (a.antigen_code IN (@Antigen))
ORDER BY S.location_code DESC
```

HELP!

Comment: You likely have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `in` works.

Comment: `antigen_code IN (@Antigen)` Blargh, I *hate* that SSRS treats that as valid at tax. I hope `antigen_code` isn't a `varchar`; otherwise you'll be suffering the same flaws that `AddWithValues` has.

Comment: @stu unfortunately SSRS *injects* when it sees that. A truly awful feature as it will often use an `nvarchar`.

Comment: That *is* awful in that case.

Comment: It's been something Ive wanted to write about for ages and not had the time... I *really* should.

Comment: *"I am also getting case insensitive results"* that's because of the collation you are using. If you need the values in the column/database to be case sensitive you should be using a case sensitive collation. Most likely it's just the column's collation you should be changing (in the table's definition). It's very unlikely you'd want your entire database to be case sensitive.

Comment: Ignoring the non-SSRS users above, I'm not sure what you mean by `get a multifield parameter to include ALL selected parameter fields that have been selected` . It looks like it should work right (other than the case sensitivity).

Comment: @ThomA The database has its collation set to case sensitive. When I run the query in designer, it will differentiate between cases, but when I run the report in Preview it becomes case insensitive.

Comment: @HannoverFist Let me see if I can clarify. If I put in C-,E- into my parameter, I want to see only units that have BOTH C- AND E-, but what it is doing is pulling all units that have EITHER C- OR E-.

Comment: The IN looks for any of the codes to match the parameter. To look for both, I think you'd need to JOIN the tvf TWICE, once for each code (the second LEFT for a blank parameter). You'll either need two parameters or rework the logic.